# Which machine learning algorithms result in trained models with deterministic execution times?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms

Which machine learning algorithms result in trained models which have a deterministic execution time?

Comment: What do you mean by deterministic execution time? If an algorithm runs on a computer it will most likely not have the same execution time for each trial. Theoretically, you can often find a bound on the number of calculations in the worst case.

Comment: Are you asking for models that, once trained, produce predictions for new examples in constant time?

Comment: @timleathart Exactly that's what I'm asking for.

Comment: Seems like pre-trained neural networks like MobileNetV2 use a constant MACs/MADDs https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet/README.md . This should imply a constant execution time, right?